# Increasing data fetching time using sqlalchemy+clickhouse using async

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-asyncio

I have the following:

```
from sqlalchemy import text
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine

engine = create_async_engine("clickhouse+asynch://host/db")

async with engine.connect() as conn:
    res = await conn.execute(text(query))
    results = res.partitions(100000) # 100K rows in each partition
```

When I first called this code to fetch a dataset of 5000000 (5M) rows, it got executed in 90s, but on subsequent calls, the same time has increased to 115-120s. For each run I cleared the memory, so I am not sure why I am getting this behavior. What can be the cause for this?